# .fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory

Tags: fonts

Upon clone .ttf fonts to `/usr/local/share/fonts

Install the font with commands

```
 sudo fc-cache -rfv
```

> -r     Erase all existing cache files and rescan.

It still report the error

```
/home/me/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/home/me/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
```

How could solve the problem?

Comment: If the directory is non-existing ? Just do nothing. If / when the directory is needed later, it will be created.

Comment: What do you want to solve? The last line is a notification that a possible cache folder does not exist. That is not really an error.  How about you create the directory?